# Authenticating users on mongo, node, passport, and heroku. Stops working after a few days

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, heroku, express

I'm creating my first full stack web app with mongo, express, angular, and node. I come from a front end background, and I'm struggling a little with the authentication implementation.

My (incomplete) app was working for days, but today it suddenly broke, and then I magically fixed it. I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything drastic in the code. The error was causing all authenticated users to see "guest users" account. It would allow them to login, but the user would come back from mongo as guestuser. Do you see anything I'm missing in this code?

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    api = require('./routes/api'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = module.exports = express();

var uristring = 
process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 
process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 
'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';

mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
  if (err) { 
  console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
  } else {
  console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
  }
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Tasks = new Schema({
    "title": String,
    "description": String,
    "difficulty": Number,
    "completed": Boolean
}); 

var Project = new Schema({
    "title": String,
    "tasks": [ Tasks ]
});

var User = new Schema({ // update data model here
    "first_name": String,
    "last_name": String,
    "email": {type: String, unique: true},
    "username": {type: String, unique: true},
    "password": String,
    "projects": [ Project ]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', User);
    User.prototype.validPassword = function(pass) {
    return (this.password === pass);
}

/**
 * Configuration
 */

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboardcat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);

// development only
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// production only
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  // TODO
};

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    mongoose.model('User').findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {   
      if (err) { 
        console.log('There was an error');
        return done(err); 
      }
      if (!user) {
        console.log('Username invalid');
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        console.log('Password incorrect');
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


/**
 * Routes
 */

// serve index and view partials
app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.user);
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.render('login');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { 
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.body.username;
    res.redirect('/');
});
app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.render('signup');   
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = undefined;
    res.redirect('/login');
});

app.post('/signup', function(req,res) {
    if (req.body.username && req.body.password) {
        var user = new User({
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(user.username);
                req.session.user = req.body.username;
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/signup');
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/signup');
    }
});

app.get('/person', function(req,res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        mongoose.model('User').findOne({username: new RegExp('^'+req.session.user+'$', "i")}, function(err, user) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                res.send(user);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});

app.put('/person', function(req,res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        console.log('Updating user');
        console.log(req.body.projects);
        mongoose.model('User').findOne({username: new RegExp('^'+req.session.user+'$', "i")}, function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            user.projects = req.body.projects;
            console.log(user.first_name + ' is here');
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('User updated');
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});


app.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else if (req.params.user != req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/' + req.session.user);
    } else {
        res.render('index');
    }
});



app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

// JSON API
app.get('/api/name', api.name);

// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.render('login');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});


/**
 * Start Server
 */

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: You may want to grab the records out of your Mongo DB and verify they are valid JSON (JSON Lint). Be sure to encode URI components, escape vals, validate your fields. It's possible bad data could have been causing server response to fail and then defaulting back

Comment: I think the /user route could be suspect, too - maybe something went wrong with the sessions middleware and sent them to /index as a guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you got most of your code from [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/), I can see you made a change to it that might have caused the failure.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    mongoose.model('User').findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
```

You have added `validPassword` to `User` , so probably that should be

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since:

> the user would come back from mongo as guestuser

... you should probably put some logging and/or error handling here:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

to help you track it down.  Since you're just getting started, I'd suggest you take a look at winston and loggly if you want to explore tooling up your logging in node/heroku.

Your application looks very "bouncy", to coin a phrase -- lots of redirects that seem sort of all over the place.  Have you looked at [fnakstad's technique](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth) for node/angular authentication?  (Note that the github page references two blog posts that explain things).  It might give you some ideas on how to get things under control.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will check into that and get back with you.